# Book about a planet facing a population crisis due to lack of non-sterile men

Tags: story-identification, books

A dear friend has been trying for years to remember the name of a book she once read without success, and since a lot of y'all are well-read nerds I figured trawling the hive-mind might help.

Here's what I know about the book and its plot, as described by my friend (some details could definitely be off because of how long it's been since she's read it):

- It was published minimum 15 years ago (when my friend first read it) but could definitely be older than that- My friend thinks eighties, though this is a guess
- The main character's name is probably Diana (or maybe Diane)
- It's a scifi story set in the far future, on a planet colonised by humans
- The population is declining because, for some reason fewer males are being born; rarer still are ones who aren't sterile
- A group from another community travel to Diana's settlement seeking to join them; they reveal that among their number are men who are capable of impregnating someone
- Diana is sent to scout the community they came from in order to note whether she notices anything that could be a dealbreaker
- During her travels Diana is injured then found and nursed back to health by someone whose name is likely Robin, a man who's living in disguise as a woman because he just wants to be left the hell alone
- Diana becomes pregnant at some point, Robin is likely not her baby's father (I don't think there's any romance between them)
- Between her friendship with Robin and observing the culture of the more permissive community she was meant to scout out and comparing it to her own, Diana comes to appreciate that individuals whose freedom has been restricted due to their status as viable reproductive partners live unfairly limited lives (not Handmaid's Tale level restricted, but not allowed to perform any activities that might involve risk to their physical safety, IE chopping wood)
- Robin is found out and taken captive, Diana joins the local equivalent of the police/military to rescue him
- Robin is rescued, Diana returns home to discover that the group who sought to join her community earlier in the book have successfully integrated into it

Comment: I immediately thought of _[Califia's Daughters](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/483007.Califia_s_Daughters)_, but that is set on Earth.

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much. It's post-apocalyptic, not set in space, but it's been long enough that my friend must have misremembered some things. The rest of it sounds so similar that it has to be the same book. I'm so grateful, I was starting to think I'd never find it!